# Minecraft LAN Part Tournment

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, pc, minecraft-java-edition-server, networking

Recently i was helping out at i52 and saw the minecraft hunger games tournament on LAN, I was wondering if you had an idea how they did the following things:

1. Setup the PC Networking through local website, which you can enter the pc name and it register it to the network and apply it to the pc.
2. Minecraft they had it when you execute the script opens minecraft and goes full screen (they are starting minecraft using silent flags) skips the login screen goes to the server connection.
3. Once joined it ask you to enter any username and press okay, waits for the rest to get ready and starts.
4. Once someone dies they cant get back into the game.

I know they where using mcmyadmin to control the servers.

Answer (score 1):

**1)** I am not exactly sure what the question is asking. It seems to vague, what are you trying to accomplish
**2)** As far as I can tell, no you cannot directly go to Minecraft without accepting the login screen. This is to make sure other people on your computer can't use Minecraft without your permission. You can save the log on details to make this faster
**3) & 4)** Both of these can be accomplished through the use of plugins from CraftBukkit. This cannot be achieved from a vanilla server. You NEED your server to be a Bukkit server, simply search online for more details

Comment: Oh okay thanks, I think i should be able to work somthing out and ill post later..

Comment: Thats OK @Arsalan.